# How to build a Prediction Request using the Google Apis objective c client library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Need to add input body to this query to predict the output. While passing the csv instance as a parameter it throws "No invalid input" error. How do i add the input body correctly?

```
GTLQueryPrediction *query = [GTLQueryPrediction queryForTrainedmodelsPredictWithProject:@"Project Name"     identifier:@"Identifier"];
query.csvInstance = array;`
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found this, to add an input body to the query "input" should be of type
GTLPredictionTrainedmodelsPredictInput.

GTLPredictionTrainedmodelsPredictInput *inputModel  = [GTLPredictionTrainedmodelsPredictInput objectWithJSON:inputData];

"inputData" is your csvInstance with JSON object.

GTLQueryPrediction *query = 
[GTLQueryPrediction queryForTrainedmodelsPredictWithProject:@"Project Name"     identifier:@"Identifier"];

query.input = inputModel;